# Obvious phenotypic inheritance markers in humans

Tags: genetics

In humans, are there phenotypic markers that prove parenthood? For example, if mother and father have `<trait characteristic>` (let's say, specific ear lobe form), then any child will have `<trait characteristic>`. If the child does not exhibit that characteristic, than either father or mother or both are only alleged, not actual.

Comment: Interesting question. Eye and hair colour (two "obvious" ones), to my knowledge, can be different from either parent due to the dominant/recessive nature of alleles. I would be interested to know of any "true" <trait characteristic>, as you put it

Comment: I've previously heard claims that a cleft chin is such a trait, but this seems to be a myth: udel.edu/~mcdonald/mythcleftchin.html. The trait supposedly has a strong heritable component though. Blood type could sometimes be a strong indication of parenthood (e.g. an O father should normally not produce AB offspring), but not always.

Comment: Not that I know of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. To determine the genetic relationship (if any) between two individuals requires molecular evidence based on genetic markers in their somatic DNA. Using phenotypes *could* be misleading because a genetic marker (an allele) can have variable penetrance (the percentage of carriers who actually have the phenotype) *and* variable expressivity (the severity or degree of the phenotype). Some of this variability can come from gene-environment interactions, and some could come from epigenetic effects (ie non-heritable).